# Polynomial-Time reduction: Clique Problem

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

Here is an exercise my friend proposed to me:

Show that the maximum clique problem polynomial time reduces to the maximum independent set problem.

Here is my attempt at solving it:

> It is known that the maximum independent set problem and the maximum
>   clique problem are polynomially equivalent.
>
> *Proof of statement:*
>   -We know that a maximum independent set is simply
>   the largest maximal independent set, where an independent set is a set
>   of non-adjacent nodes in a graph.
>
> -We know that the maximum clique is defined as the largest clique,
>   which is a fully connected subgraph.
>
> -The complement of a clique, then, is an independent set, and vice
>   versa. Thus, finding the maximum clique is equivalent to finding the
>   maximum independent set, and vice versa.

So here's where I'm running into a wall... I can demonstrate equivalency between the two problems, but I can't demonstrate reduction from the Clique problem to the Independent set problem... It seems to me that they have the same complexity, so

> Maximum Independent Set Problem ~ $\Theta$(Maximum Clique Problem)

Can anyone weigh in on this problem? I feel like I'm overlooking something important.

Thank you very much!

Comment: hint: consider the complement graph.